# Angular Material Datepicker - full month name

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material, mat-datepicker

In my project, I am using mat-datepicker. By manual, I installed "moment" and "@angular/material-moment-adapter".
To app.module.ts I added:

```
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS }
]
```

now in pickers input I am getting the date in the format

```
12/31/2020
```

but I need the date to be displayed in the format

```
31 December, 2020
```

What else do I need to add to do this?

I can't find a manual that explains how to set custom formats in object

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you please provide your full component file(s), because [the example provided by Angular Material](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jlbylrdrjgq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-formats-example.ts) is pretty clear and works.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `dateInput:'LL'`  by  `dateInput: 'DD MMMM YYYY'` in  display.
Something like this:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD MMMM YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'DD MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
```

Comment: @Alex  first Merry xmas.
I made this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sijm1s?file=src/app/datepicker-formats-example.ts) and this answer seems to work.